# Does anyone knows about a good example of SQLite on Xamarin.Mac / Monomac?

Tags: macos, sqlite, xamarin, monomac, xamarin.mac

Hi i have been searching over the net for a few hours but can't find any example of Xamarin.MAc using SQLite can any of you guide me on the right path? since have been awful to try to make the app i want with such little (i meant none) documentation

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to my question, you can use sqlite-net and works perfectly fine, but no on PCL (guess someone have to make the implementation or something like that for this platform).

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin has quite a few examples for iOS using SQLite.  The easiest being Tasky:

https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/tree/master/TaskyPro

Case Study of Tasky:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/case_study-tasky/

This example uses a core library which is where the SQLite database code is stored.  This particular example uses Linq to interact with the database, though that's not required.  The iOS specific code interacts with the TaskManager.

The database structure goes as follows:

TaskDatabase-> TaskRepository-> TaskManager

- TaskDatabase is where the database is initialized and the database
  functions are written.
- TaskRepository references the database
  functions and also contains the database path and manages the
  connection.  If you wanted to write pure sql, you'd do that here.
  TaskManager references the functions outlined in
- TaskRepository -
  this is what the iOS, Android, and Windows projects call in order to 
  interact with the database.

Comment: Thank you Coridan, but for what i'm loking is for Xamarin.Mac (Cocoa, OS X) not Xamarin.iOS (iOS, Cocoa-Touch), but that's right! they really have good examples on the Xamarin.iOS world, but they forgot of Xamarin.Mac or something like that, don't know really